# How to put object in front of another? (Unity 2d)

Tags: unity-game-engine, overlap

[image]

I would like to put the red cube above the gray area like the green one.

I tried pulling it up on the z axis but nothing  happens and i found nothing on google but this seems like it should be something easy to do. Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the order layer. Definitely more number puts the layer forward.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok so my bad turns out the camera was on the negative side of the z axis so all i had to do was pull it down instead of pulling it up